# Node express app calling mssql is saying that Connection is closed

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express, promise

I have another app which uses express and routes but this new app i was slimming it down.  I know the connection string stuff is correct

```
script.getQuestions(connection);

script.getQuestions = function(connection,req, res){
   console.log(connection);
}
```

I have read that some people said online to change to use a promise for async fixes this... problem is that with my function having `req` and `res` i don't know how to pass those in when i even try to refactor with a promise

**"ConnectionError: Connection is closed"**

**"(module.js:487:32) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }"**

What I call up (script)  is

```
var sql = require('mssql');

exports.getQuestions = function(connection, req,res){
 console.log(connection);
var request = new sql.Request(connection);

var query = 'select * from Question'
request.query(query).then(function(resultset){
    res.json(resultset.recordset);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    //res.json(err)
})
}
```

Comment: `problem is that with my function having req and res i don't` .... you don't what? finish a sentence? which exact line of code issues that error?

Comment: fixed,  req and res don't work in my promise refactor ..   I get error from the sql server execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit hard to understand what you're doing there. But here is an promise example to use `mssql`

```
const sql = require('mssql')

sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    // Query 

    return pool.request()
    .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
    .query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter')
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)

    // Stored procedure 

    return pool.request()
    .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
    .output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50))
    .execute('procedure_name')
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks 
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler 
})
```

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises